# Convert String text to Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Is it possible to convert string text that is inside an `EditText` box into a Bitmap? In other words, is there any way to convert string text into a Bitmap that means the text will display as an image?

Below is my Code:

```
class TextToImage extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //create String object to be converted to image
        String sampleText = "SAMPLE TEXT";
        String fileName = "Image";

        //create a File Object
        File newFile = new File("./" + fileName + ".jpeg");

        //create the font you wish to use
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);

        //create the FontRenderContext object which helps us to measure the text
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 94):

You can create a Bitmap of the appropriate size, create a Canvas for the Bitmap, and then draw your text into it. You can use a Paint object to measure the text so you'll know the size needed for the bitmap. You can do something like this (untested):

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: @shyam - these are all Android classes, not AWT classes. They are in package `android.graphics`

Comment: hey Ted Hopp i use canvas.drawText() for drawing the text on canvas now i want to move it on touch of text means move text on finger motion..i have the code for moving image on surface of canvas ..if it is possible to make text as image then i can use it as image and move text on screen ..so how to convert text in to BitMap for move it on screen?

Comment: Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.RED);
  paint.setTextSize(16);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
  // fills the canvas with black
  c.drawText("shyam ji ", 10, 16, paint);

Comment: Two fixes to the code: 
1) use text ascent absolute value (i.e. Math.abs(paint.ascent()))
2) make text left aligned (i.e. paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT))

Comment: @RuslanYanchyshyn - Thanks for catching those! Now fixed.

Comment: @TedHopp When i set  paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);, the text cuts-off. do you why is it happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: @Fahim - Without seeing your code and without any details about how it is cut off, it's hard to say. However, I suspect a coordinate system problem. When you set the text alignment to `CENTER`, you need to provide the center coordinate (not the left edge) for where you want the text when you call `drawText`, using the current coordinate system for the canvas.

Comment: Thanks, Ted, for the brilliant answer! The rectangular image was being stretched when used in certain places, so I altered the code to make the image always square (see my answer below).

Comment: I've been searching forever for a simple way to do this.  I was going through the hassle of encoding strings and it wasn't working.  Turns out all that was unnecessary.  Plus, that way wouldn't let you mess with the Font settings.  Excellent!

Comment: black background is coming, how to remove in order to get only the text as output?

Comment: @KrishnaCh - It would be best if you posted a separate question and included all the relevant code and perhaps an image of the problem as well. But perhaps your question has already been answered in this question: [How to make Canvas draw area transparent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8703581/535871). The issue there wasn't the bitmap, it was the properties of the view on which it was rendered.

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for the response, I've solved by adding this : canvas.drawColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

Comment: @KrishnaCh - I'm glad you solved it. If `R.color.white` is just white, you can use the predefined constant `Color.WHITE` as the argument to `drawColor` instead of looking up a color resource value. (However, don't do this if you want the background color to change with the theme or if it might not always be white in the future.)

Comment: @TedHopp sure ill try that, and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
    public static Bitmap drawText(String text, int textWidth, int textSize) {
// Get text dimensions
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
| Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint,
textWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

// Create bitmap and canvas to draw to
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textWidth, mTextLayout.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

// Draw background
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
| Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
c.drawPaint(paint);

// Draw text
c.save();
c.translate(0, 0);
mTextLayout.draw(c);
c.restore();

return b;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've adapted @[TedHopp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799344/1476989)'s answer to ensure the image created is **always square**, which can be useful depending on where the image is to be displayed, such as in a `NavigationDrawer` icon or suchlike. The text is horizontally centered in the middle of the image.

```
public static Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    // adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799344/1476989
    Paint paint = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.0f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.0f);

    int trueWidth = width;
    if(width>height)height=width; else width=height;
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, width/2-trueWidth/2, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = "Hello world!";
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
textPaint.setTextSize(16.0F);
StaticLayout sl= new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, b.getWidth()-8, Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
c.translate(6, 40);
sl.draw(c);
return b
```

Answer (score 0):

For only String I don't know but,

You will get `Bitmap image of the whole EditText` not only String with this,

```
mEditText.setCursorVisible(false); 
mEditText.buildDrawingCache(); 
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mEditText.getDrawingCache());
```