# Creating a bitmap and set it as action bar icon. Possible?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-drawable

Is it possible to create a image from a textview and imageview and set the appicon to the image?

Something like this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    tv.setText("Hello");

    tv.buildDrawingCache();
    ImageView img = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
    img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());

    img.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmap);

    getActionBar().setIcon(d);
```

Comment: You can set your app icon programatically like this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Sorry, not the appicon, the actionbar icon. Changed the topic.

Comment: You want to nest the TextViews text inside the ImageView and then create a Bitmap of that and set it as the ActionBar icon?

Comment: Yes that's correct sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a Canvas ? 
[Convert String text to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799290/convert-string-text-to-bitmap-android)

You can draw texts and bitmap and then set the icon of the actionbar.
You can get the Bitmap of a ImageView with :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

And then draw the text and the bitmap in the canvas and generate a Bitmap from that.
Using drawing cache is possible but not advised.

As for your question, you should try your method before asking if it will work here.