# How to convert the text to bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw, bitmapfactory

please help me to draw a text with rounded rectangle as background. I have to draw many texts on a canvas and the text has rounded background. SO what I am trying is to write a function "createTextBitmap" which return a bitmap image so that we can draw image(which return by the function) on a main canvas.
the 'createTextBitmap'function can return a created bitmap, the bitmap image is the one,which contains the text with rounded edge background...

i have tried one, which gives below.

```
 private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(String text,Paint paint, boolean lastPoint){
    Bitmap bm1 = null;
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    float width = bounds.width();
    float height =bounds.height();
    float radius;
    if (width > height){
        radius = height/4;
    }else{
        radius = width/4;
    }
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(5);   
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    float center_x, center_y;
    center_x = width/4;
    center_y = height/4;
    final RectF rect = new RectF();
    rect.set(center_x - radius, 
            center_y - radius, 
            center_x + radius, 
            center_y + radius);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
    canvas2.drawRoundRect(rect, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas2.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
    return newBitmap;
     }
```

and my question is How can we convert this canvas2 to a bitmap image? and image has the size  of text bounds,
  which look like[image: a sample which i need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert your canvas into bitmap please do the following :

```
public Bitmap convertCanvasToBitmap(int width , int height) {
        Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;

        try {
            drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
// now draw anything you want to the canvas 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawnBitmap;
}
```

so the idea is just pass the bitmap to the canvas , draw with the canvas it will be drawn into your bitmap .

and please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799290/convert-string-text-to-bitmap/8799344#8799344) to see how to deal with the text size in the bitmap .

and please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: oh... but this size is too large, right? here the size is 400X400.. i need the bitmap size based on the text size...

Comment: you change the size as you want

Comment: but how we get the width and height from a text i used the Rect object to get the bounds but its not working

Comment: your question is how to convert this canvas2 to a bitmap image not how to get the width and height from a text

Comment: Sorry for the confussion my exact question is given with the question, that is how to convert the canvas2 to bitmap, but i need that bitmap which has the limited size, not like 400X400

Comment: Yes... Amrola.... finally i got what i expect.. you helped me a lot and the new link to "how to convert the text to bitmap"...

Comment: glad that i could help .

Answer (score 1):

you can create a bitmap, then call draw on that bitmap, something like this:

```
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rect.width, rect.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(newBitmap);
```

Comment: yaa i have tried this one. but which is very small, like a dot.

Comment: I need to draw bitmap image, with given text, since the image need width and height based on the text length...

Comment: you need to measure text first, and create bitmap according to the measured size, then draw on the canvas, which step are you stuck at?