# EOS POS printer Font size - Android

Tags: android, printing, fonts, thermal-printer

I am trying to decrease font size for printing but unable to do this I have used this for small font size

```
val FONT_SMALL = byteArrayOf(0x1B, 0x21, 0x001)
```

But I want decrease more font size

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the vendor and model of printer you are using.
For example, for EPSON, specifying Font C with the following command will result in a smaller font.
But whether it is supported or not depends on the printer model.

[ESC M](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=27)

---

In response to comment:

This is a command that changes the printer font for subsequent prints.
After sending this command, if you send the character string data you want to print, it will be printed with the changed font size.

Comment: How to use Font C with smaller size can you please give me example

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API of the device. I also could not change the font size of the text of the receipt-printing POS device.

The device that I had did use JNI with some binary files for printing. So, the only solution was to decompile them but this method could take a lot of time so I decided not to go this way.

The device also could print bitmaps, so I created a bitmap with the text that I need and this solved my problem.

To create a bitmap with text on it these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799290/convert-string-text-to-bitmap) can be helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33905948)