# Fill a canvas with a transparent color in Android

Tags: android, colors, imageview, transparency, android-canvas

Good Morning,

I have an `ImageView` that I initialized with `#99aaaaaa` color (it corresponds to 153,170, 170,170). after that I draw some lines with different colors. and Now I want to Fill my Canvas with the original color (`#99aaaaaa)`.

The method `myCanvas.drawColor(OriginalColor)` fills the canvas with OriginalColor, but the lines still visible

```
    myPaint.setColor(OriginalColor);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    myCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, 170, 170, myPaint); // my ImageView is  170X170
```

Also let lines visible.

Any help please, Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703581/how-to-make-canvas-draw-area-transparent-in-android

Comment: @Triode I think that no relation with my question, I saw this before asking

Comment: In my case I am drawing on the transparent (argb , a = 153) canvas, after that I want to reinitialize the canvas color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the canvas original color is semi transparent, then you draw something on it and draw another layer of semi transparent stuff, then its pretty obvious youll see the level-down-layer through the top **transparent** layer isnt it? another words, if you place a half transparent glass on your knees, ull still see the knees through it

Answer (score 1):

Set the transfer mode as follows, before calling drawRec():

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
```

Reset the painter afterwards, for further drawing:

```
paint.setXfermode(null);
paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```