# Change Custom View Canvas background color to transparent

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw, android-custom-view

I made a custom View Class that draws the waveform of an audio file, unfortunately, I'm having some problems with changing the background color of the canvas/custom view to transparent.

I can change the background color inside the onDraw function canvas.drawColor(Color.WHATEVER);

However, this works with any color but transparent, which shows black instead.

**This works:** canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

**This doesn't:** canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Also, if I use the Android Studio Layout inspector, it seems to actually work, but in reality it does not. See the screenshot here:
[Layout Inspector vs Android Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEXLg.png)

```
public class SimpleWaveform extends View {
    Context context;
    public Paint beforePlaySectionPencil = new Paint();
    public Paint playSectionPencil = new Paint();
    public Paint afterPlaySectionPencil = new Paint();   

    public Paint peakPencilBefore = new Paint();
    public Paint peakPencilPlay = new Paint();
    public Paint peakPencilAfter = new Paint(); 

    public Paint xAxisPencil = new Paint();

    public void init() {
        beforePlaySectionPencil.setStrokeWidth(10);//set bar width (ERA /2)
        beforePlaySectionPencil.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.aaDarkBlue));

        playSectionPencil.setStrokeWidth(10); // (ERA /2)
        playSectionPencil.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.aaLightBlue));

        afterPlaySectionPencil.setStrokeWidth(10); // (ERA /2)
        afterPlaySectionPencil.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.aaDarkBlue));

        peakPencilBefore.setStrokeWidth(barGap / 8);//set peak outline width (ERA /6)
        peakPencilBefore.setColor(0xfffe2f3f);

        peakPencilPlay.setStrokeWidth(barGap / 8);  //(ERA /6)
        peakPencilPlay.setColor(0xfffe2f3f);

        peakPencilAfter.setStrokeWidth(barGap / 8);  //(ERA /6)
        peakPencilAfter.setColor(0xfffe2f3f);

        xAxisPencil.setStrokeWidth(1);
        xAxisPencil.setColor(0x88ffffff);
       
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (clearScreenListener != null) {
            clearScreenListener.clearScreen(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        }

        if (clearScreen) {
            clearScreen = false;
            return;
        }

        drawWaveList(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    private void drawWaveList(Canvas canvas) {
        
        if (showBar) {
            canvas.drawLines(barPoints, 0, playSectionLeftOffset * barUnitSize, beforePlaySectionPencil);
            canvas.drawLines(barPoints, playSectionLeftOffset * barUnitSize, (playSectionRightOffset - playSectionLeftOffset) * barUnitSize, playSectionPencil);
            canvas.drawLines(barPoints, playSectionRightOffset * barUnitSize, (barNum - playSectionRightOffset) * barUnitSize, afterPlaySectionPencil);
        }

        if(showXAxis){
            canvas.drawLines(xAxisPoints, xAxisPencil);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and found out how to achieve that in a canvas.
Take a look at this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703581/how-to-make-canvas-draw-area-transparent-in-android).

Comment: setBackground is not a method of the Canvas class in Android